# Log when user access to endpoint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to create a custom CBV so I can log everytime an user access to any endpoint which use this custom CBV. I've tried with something like this:

```
class LogUserAccess(APIView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info('User {} accessing to {} ({})'.format(request.user, resolve(request.path).app_name, self.__class__.__name__))
        super(LogUserAccess, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

... but doesn't recognize the logger instance.

What would do the best approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using middleware. In this case, you can try process_request middleware. Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/)

```
def process_request(self, request):
     logger.info('User {} accessing to {} ({})'.format(request.user, resolve(request.path).app_name, self.__class__.__name__))
```

Comment: It won't have access to the logger instance, rigth?

Comment: You have. And you can do something like this.

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger({logger name})